# How can I concatenate a variable with another string variable in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

How can I concatenate a variable with another string variable in Selenium?
For example, Date0,Date1,Date2..etc are variables and have the actual time and date.
Here is the code:

```
dar = time.localtime(time.time())
das = time.localtime(time.time() + 86400)
Date0 = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dar)
Date1 = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",das)
```

The problem in Selenium I'm facing while executing the Python script

```
for i in range(5):
        for j in range(4,7):
            if (str(i) == '0' or str(i) == '1' or str(i) == '2' or str(i) == '3' or str(i) == '4')and(str(j) == '4' or str(j) == '5' or str(j) == '6'):
                hrs_fill = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='"+ Date+str(i) +"_50"+ str(j) +"_166003-5_hrs']")
                hrs_fill.send_keys('3')
                break
```

Getting the error:

> NameError: name 'Date' is not defined

It's considering `Date` as separate variable and `str(i)` as separate variable not as combined

Comment: try str(Date+str(i))

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict`

**Ex:**

```
import time
dar = time.localtime(time.time())
das = time.localtime(time.time() + 86400)
date = {"Date0": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dar), "Date1": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",das)}
print(date["Date"+str(0)])
```

---

```
date = {"Date0": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",dar), "Date1": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",das)}
hrs_fill = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='"+ date["Date"+str(i)] +"_50"+ str(j) +"_166003-5_hrs']")
```

Comment: Problem is in xpath for identifying both the variable as separate variables rather than combined variable

Comment: Thanks , it worked. I have a small query,with that I am able to iterate 1st column and corresponding 3 rows are working but 2nd columns onwards columns are getting iterated but rows are not getting iterated

Answer (score 0):

Use the operator `+` if you're dealing with strings like

```
String myString1 = "Hey Dude..." + "How are you?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You create variables called Date0 and Date1, but you called only 'Date' on the code.
Try:

```
"//*[@id='"+ Date0+str(i) +"_50"+ str(j) +"_166003-5_hrs']"
```

or

```
"//*[@id='"+ Date1+str(i) +"_50"+ str(j) +"_166003-5_hrs']"
```